# MySQL query the events for a calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm building a SaaS calendar with MySQL & PHP.

The front-end javascript calendar lib is fullcalendar(monthly view)
http://fullcalendar.io/

I have a mysql data table named `events` like this:

- ID
- ID_USER
- BODY_NAME
- BODY_START
- BODY_END
- IS_DONE
- TIME_CREATED
- TIME_UPDATED
- TIME_DELETED

The `BODY_START` and `BODY_END` is using unix_timestamp.

Then in my PHP code, I built a query helper that generate a SQL like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `" . $this->_tableName . "` WHERE `ID_ACCOUNT` = '$_id_account' AND (( `BODY_START` >= 1424649600 AND `BODY_START` <= 1428278400 ) OR (`BODY_END` >= 1424649600 AND `BODY_END` <= 1428278400))";
```

The start and end timestamp params provided by the fullcalendar.

There is a question:

if the event is crossing the current month, it will not be shown.

example:

- ID `f8a58d0c8280db2340863a1ac7aa60b0`
- ID_USER `e576c22ce89f38ee422ec818807b99b8`
- BODY_NAME `test_event`
- BODY_START `1422720000`
- BODY_END `1428422400`
- IS_DONE `0`
- TIME_CREATED `1422845255`
- TIME_UPDATED `0`
- TIME_DELETED `0`

If you do the query, this event will not show.

how can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: check end or start in current month- not need both

Comment: @HaimEvgi If i check the start or end only, It will returns lot's of events that not belongs the current month. YES it will work, but too much useless datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, simplify your query to be (in pseudo code):

```
  BODY_START <= month_end and BODY_END >= month_start
```

Your original query query above requires that events must either start or end during the month, but that's not actually what you want - you want any event that *exists* for any part of the month.